# How to keep local commits in Git when sending pull requests

Tags: git

I'm currently working on a shared git repository, where the primary way to submit new code is through a pull request. What I would like to do is be able to have local commits available from any branch, *without* having to send those whenever I make a pull request against upstream. My current solution involves stashing to "switch" on and off those commits, but that's not ideal.

Is there a better way to tell Git to ignore certain commits when doing pull requests? New files are easy enough to ignore, but changes that modify files are pretty troublesome... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do local branches, one for your 'private' work, one for your 'pull request' or 'public' work.

Create a private branch, and commit anything you want

```
git checkout -b private
[edit, ...]
git add / commit / rebase / ...
```

Create a public branch (from master)

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b public
```

Get the changes you want to publish from your private branch (for example)

```
git merge private public
git cherry-pick <sha-1 from private>
....
```

Finally create your pull request from the public branch.

See [Git workflows](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows) for more details and other branching strategies.

Hope this helps